# Пункт контекстного меню "Создать ярлык"

Tags: windows, menu, реестр, explorer

В настоящий момент создать ярлык можно, вызвав контекстное меню "Создать" -> "Ярлык"
Как сделать так, чтобы этот пункт меню был сразу доступен в первом меню?
То есть чтобы не выбирать пункт "Создать", а примерно вот так:
Правый клик мышки в проводнике -> Контекстное меню проводника -> "Создать ярлык"
В интернете приводятся способы удаления пунктов меню, создания новых пунктов для определённых типов файлов по шаблону. Но нет способа, который мне нужен

Comment: А что на счёт перетаскивания цели ярлыка правой кнопкой мыши?

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно делать много ярлыков, которые ссылаются на разные сайты. Клик правой кнопкой по объекту в моем случае невозможен. Я щелкаю мышкой в той папке, в которой хочу разместить ярлык. По свободному месту внутри папки.

Comment: Поэтому редактирую раздел реестра HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\background

Comment: На данный момент выяснил, что за вызов мастера создания ярлыка (это когда сначала указываешь расположение нужного объекта, то есть адрес сайта в мое случае, а потом указываешь название ярлыка, его имя) отвечает объект Windows {ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af} New Shortcut Wizard. Его можно вызвать в командной строке как rundll.exe appwiz.cpl,NewLinkHere <путь к расположению нового ярлыка>. Однако мастер вызывается, но ярлык не создается. Пишу с мобильного, позже выложу код reg-файла, который есть на данный момент.